# Configuring Firefox sync on a PC with an already configured Android phone

Tags: firefox, sync, android

I have a Firefox Sync account that I created on my home PC.
I have also configured this Firefox Sync accout on my Android phone by following the standard procedure of entering a phone-generated code on my PC.

Now I want to configure another PC with this account and I cannot find a way to do it with my phone... (I am away from my home PC): the "sync" option in the "settings" menu only allows me to sync the phone with the cloud-stored bookmarks, not to pair a new device... (it looks like it brings the standard Android "accounts" page)

- Is it even possible? (I seem to recall doing it this way with another laptop in the past, but the software versions were different)
- If possible, how to do it?

Versions are:

- Firefox: 17
- Android: 4.1.1

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I just found the answer by looking around:

- using the firefox "settings" menu, the "sync" option brings up a list of all the "accounts" stored on my phone (Google, Dropbox, Firefox sync etc.) and when I click on "Firefox sync", I can only either synchronize my phone or delete the account... => **not possible this way**

- using the phone "settings" menu, there's a separate "accounts" subdivision under which are listed all my accounts, and when I click on the "Firefox sync" in **this** list, then I get to a screen where I can pair a new device!

Seems like a Firefox bug to me...

Comment: Because I'm a new user, I couldn't post an "answer" so I posted a "comment". This botched up the formatting... I'll post that as an answer when the "lock" is lifted, in several hours...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I just found the answer by looking around:

- using the firefox "settings" menu, the "sync" option brings up a list of all the "accounts" stored on my phone (Google, Dropbox, Firefox sync etc.) and when I click on "Firefox sync", I can only either synchronize my phone or delete the account... => **not possible this way**
- using the phone "settings" menu, there's a separate "accounts" subdivision under which are listed all my accounts, and when I click on the "Firefox sync" in this list, then I get to a screen where I can pair a new device!

Seems like a Firefox bug to me...